# expectation of cauchy distribution when power less than 1

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, statistical-inference

How do I prove that $E|X|^p$, p<1 is less than infinity when $X$ is Cauchy distributed?

The pdf is $f(x) = 1/\pi(1+x^2)$.

When $p=1$, EX integrates nicely to $\frac{1}{2\pi} \ln(1+x^2)$, but its not so nice when eg $p=1/2$. Then we get something like $\ln \left|2x+2^{1+\frac{1}{2}}x^{\frac{1}{2}}+2\right| - arctan(...)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E|X|^{p}=\int\frac {|x|^{p}} {\pi (1+x^{2})}dx\leq \int_{-1}^{1} \frac 1 {\pi} |x|^{p}dx+\frac 1{\pi} \int_{|x|>1} \frac 1  {|x|^{2-p}}dx<\infty$.

Comment: why can you remove $x^p$ in the second integral on the right hand side?

Comment: @EndreMoen I have used the facts that $1+x^{2} \geq x^{2}$ and $\frac {x^{p}} {x^{2}}=\frac 1 {x^{p-2}}$.